# Useful books/materials for private lessons in German

Tags: resource, book

As a small hobby or even sidejob, I am planning to give private lessons in German
for people with 1) no or low knowledge in German, 2) medium or good abilities. Can you recommend any books or other materials for such a work?

Comment: Do you mean you need German (books/materials)? by the title, one would get the impression that the books or materials need to be in German, I guess what you wanted to ask was "useful books/materials for German private lessons". But I might be mistaken.

Comment: And there are several interesting resources had been mentioned here before, maybe you can find a bunch of them by searching in [tag:resources] and [tag:learning] or even [tag:book].

Comment: Thanks for asking. Yes, the books should be entirely in German.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These books from [Hueber](http://www.hueber.de/deutsch-als-fremdsprache/) are really nice and are actually used by most of the schools teaching German to adults; the series of books are very intelligently designed and can be chosen depending upon level of learner.

You can also buy them from any book store.

Comment: Welcome to GL&U. It is normal here to edit other people's posts if we think it helps. I edited your post to make it easier to read, but reserved the original meaning. You can revert it to your old version if you disagree.